# How to Add Hash into Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i have a **User** Model and **Address** Model.
 when i do @user=User.all
 it returns

```
  {  "id" : "1",
    "firstname" : "test",
    "username" : "test",   
  },
  {  "id" : "2",
    "firstname" : "test1",
    "username" : "test2",       
  }
```

and when i do `@address =Address.all`

```
{   "id" : "21",
    "user_id" : "1",
    "city" : "test",
    "country" : "test",   
  },
  {  "id" : "22",
     "user_id" : "2",
     "city" : "test1",
     "country" : "test2",       
  }
```

i get above value

Now i want to merge both value that is @user and @ddress in a single Hash.
 like ex-

```
   {  "id" : "1",
     "firstname" : "test",
     "username" : "test",   
     "id" : "22",
     "user_id" : "1",
     "city" : "test1",
     "country" : "test2",   
    },
   {  "id" : "2",
     "firstname" : "test2",
     "username" : "test2", 
     "id" : "22",
     "user_id" : "2",
     "city" : "test1",
     "country" : "test2",         
   }
```

How to do this?

Comment: There is a `.merge` method, which will do most of what you want. However, your example hashes have repeated key `"id"` which cannot work in Ruby's Hash class. Without the repeat id, just `combo_hash = user_hash.merge( address_hash )`

Comment: Hi @NeilSlater 
When i do so i get 
"undefined method `merge' for #<Users id: 1>"

Comment: why don't you use eager loading concept here? Like `@users = User.includes(:addresses).all`. Now this object has users and related addresses. NOw when you do `@users.first.addresses` this will give you all the addresses associated with first user in the hash/returned object. PS: I am assuming there is an `one to many` association between user and address models.

Comment: If you're more into SQL, you may use joins. I mean http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 1):

Index one array by "id" into a hash:

```
users_by_id = {}
@users.each {|h| users_by_id[h['id']] = h}
```

Next step, merge into the second hash:

```
@address.map do |address| 
   # search the user with the same id
   u = users_by_id[address['user_id']]
   if u
     # rename 'id' key
     u['uid'] = u['id']
     address.merge(u)
   else
     address # no user matched!
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to solve this issue is to alias the duplicate column in the select clause. For your address model, when you pull up each record, you can do the following:

```
@addresses = Address.select("id AS address_id, user_id, city, country").all
```

Now the ID column of your address model hash should not conflict with the ID column of your user hash. You can then merge them as Neil Slater suggested, using:

```
combo_hash = user_hash.merge(address_hash)
```